# How can i make 3 div in first row and 2 div in second row?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can i make 3 div in first row and 2 div in second row?

This is the current output:

[image: This is currently Output]

This is the target output:
[image: This is target output]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="gift-div">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-6 col-padds">
      <a href="giftred_detail.php?p=">
        <div class="div-size" style="background-color:transparent ; border : 3px solid white; box-shadow: 0px 0px 70px 5px #FF0000, inset 0px 0px 150px 5px #FF0000;;">
          <img src="img/gift/" alt="Item" class="jpo">
      </a>
      <div class="container text-con" style="text-align:center">
        <h4><b style="word-break:break-word"></b></h4>
        <p>Points</p>
      </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some more code.

Comment: Your snippet is not even close to provided images. Maybe missing `text-align: center` or use flex?

Comment: Have you tried using a col offset? Looks like, in row 2, you want it from cells 3-6 instead of 1-6. In that case, it would be `col-lg-4 offset-lg-2`

Comment: That's invalid HTML, you close the `<a>` element before the `<div>` element

Comment: I removed the tags for `Javascript` and `PHP` as I see neither of that used and as such no reason behind those tags. If you can explain me why they should be required I will re-add them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS `flex` as well:

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  gap: 50px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE: THE RESULTS HERE MAY NOT BE ACCURATE DUE TO IFRAME WIDTH**

Actual results:

[image: Results]

[**Fiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/L3q4amry/1/)

Comment: Thanks your help and your code but cant separate two class of row, if not i cant apply php,  when i apply php it would be 5 items in one row.